# Retrieving data inside a function

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to get user data by using CAKEPHP find inside a PHP function, basically it's a call back function.

Is there any way to get the data inside the call back function?

Here i am getting error "Using $this when not in object context"

```
public function links($msg=null){

$final_message = preg_replace(array('/(?i)\b((?:https?:\/\/|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:\'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))/', '/(^|[^a-z0-9_])#([a-z0-9_]+)/i'), array('<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>',  '$1<a href="/getdatabyhash/$2">#$2</a>'), $msg);

$regex = '~(?i)@[a-z]+[ ][a-z]+~';
$replaced = preg_replace_callback($regex,function ($match) {

foreach($match as $stringmatch)
{
$username= preg_replace('/@/',"",$stringmatch);
$fetchuser=$this->User->find('all', array('conditions'=>
array("User.First_Name  LIKE" => "%$username%")));

if(sizeof($fetchuser)> 0)
{
    return "<a href='@'>@</a>";
}
else
{

}
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
App::uses('ClassRegistry', 'Utility');
class whatever etc.{

    protected $User;

    public function __construct(){
         $this->User = ClassRegistry::init('User');
    } 

}
```

Comment: should i try this in my contoller class ?

Comment: it depends if you're inside a controller class you can load User model with $this->loadModel('User'); where do you use this function ?

Comment: it tried this but gives me error Call to a member function init() on a non-object in lib/Cake/Controller/Controller.php, line 639

Comment: can you add more info about the place you're trying to use the function ? is it inside a model, behavior, custom lib,  controller, component, helper or view? or something else?